# Unit test validation for a Flask-WTF form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm running a unit test for my "Register" function. Is there a way to check that all fields in the form had their validators satisfied upon submission?

```
def test_register(self):
    form = RegistrationForm()
    form.username.data = "test"
    form.email.data = "test@email.com"
```

My Registration form has a "SubmitField", I was wondering if there was a way to (within the unit test) simulate the "SubmitField" as clicked, and proceed to test whether validators for the username and email fields were satisfied using "AssertTrue()"?

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? You have `.is_submitted()`, with `()` denoting a function call, on the left hand side of `=`

Comment: I understand that this is a syntax error, but what would I have to replace it with to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Looking at [the source coce](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/flask_wtf/form.py#L138) `is_submitted` doesn't set any attributes, it simply calls `_is_submitted()` which returns a bool. In terms of testing, I don't know how to handle this situation, but that would probably have been a better opener

Answer (score 3):

You can call `form.validate()` to run field validations without mocking the request.

Normally you'd use `form.validate_on_submit()` which is just a shortcut for  `form.is_submitted()` and `form.validate()`.

[Docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_wtf.FlaskForm.validate_on_submit)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach, you have to pass in incorrect data and check that the relevant error was thrown.

```
def test_missing_field_user_registration_error(self):
    self.app.get('/register', follow_redirects=True)
    response = self.register('patkennedy79@gmail.com', 'FlaskIsAwesome', '')
    self.assertIn(b'This field is required.', response.data)
```

https://gitlab.com/patkennedy79/flask_recipe_app/blob/master/web/project/tests/test_users.py